# Does JOptionPane.showInputDialog() return a different String

Tags: java, string, swing, joptionpane, string-comparison

Is the String returned by `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` different from a regular String? When I try to compare it with `"2"`, it returns false and go to the else block.

```
        // Prompt user for the month
        String monthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Enter which month are you looking for: "); 

        // SMALL Months, ie: 2, 4, 6, 9, 11
        else {
            // Special case on February
            if (monthString == "2" && isLeap) 
                            result += "29 days!";
            else if (monthString == "2")
                result += "28 days!";
            // Everytime my code to go to this block instead
            else
                result += "30 days!";
        }
```

Only work if I parse month to Int and then compare it with literal 2. Why do my original version does not work?

```
int month = Integer.parseInt(monthString);
if (month == 2 && isLeap) ...
```

Comment: Use monthString.equals("2") when you compare Strings.

Comment: @brano88 use "2".equals(monthString) when you compare Strings. It should always be constant.equals(variable) as it takes out the possibility of a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use equals to compare string and not ==

Change this:

```
monthString == "2"
```

to

```
"2".equals(monthString)
```

in your if blocks

Equals compare the string contents while == compares the object equality. Read more from the related post here:

[Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Also note the reverse comparision "2" against the monthStirng. This will prevent null pointer exception in case monthString is null.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `==` to compare Strings. Strings are reference types, meaning that when you write:

```
monthString == "2"
```

You are **not** testing whether `monthString` represents the character sequence "2". You are actually testing whether `monthString` is **excatly the same obect in memory** as the "2" literal that follows it. This may or may not be true, depending on how the Strings are declared, but in general it is always better to use the `equals` method instead. This should solve your problem:

```
if (monthString.equals("2"))
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/1530508) is a much more complete overview of the differences between `==` and `.equals`.